# How to write outline data into .otf files?

Tags: python, postscript, bezier, opentype

I need to edit or completely replace outline data (bezier curves) of OpenType fonts. the input data is an EPS file that i have to write it into one specified glyph of an otf file with a certain scaling. (The glyph is specified by PostScript name OR Unicode value.)

I need something like an encoder (or just a library of file structure of OpenType)?
where to find about structure of otf and ttf files?

Note: python-realated tools and libraries are performed :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/python.html) python extensions.